# Issues Hosting PHP app with Slim Framework on VPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, vps

I have a PHP application that is using Slim framework for APIs. Everything is working fine on localhost...however... not on the VPS..I am using Digital Ocean.

Here is my project structure.... Just wanted to ensure whether it is right.

ROOT DIRECTORY
- app

-- admin - index.php (Main App Homepage)
           - .htaccess

### - Other CSS & javaScript

- API (This is Slim Project)
  -- includes
  -- lib
  -- v1

  - .htaccess (htaccess of Slim)
    -- index.html

MAIN ISSUE:

On running the app... say login page...it makes a request to the Slim ...the api responds back with the json...but it shows in the browser rather than showing the html formatted response.

Not sure what is missing.
.htaccess for Slim

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

.htaccess for main app

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the content-type to application/json ?
Check [this](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json), Slim has a simple way to return a json, this way :

```
    $data = array('name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 40);
    $newResponse = $oldResponse->withJson($data);
```

Comment: Yes... everything is working fonr on localhost... This might be an issue with Project Structure or .htaccess